# How long does a Red Flag stay in Airport system

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, thailand, visa-free-entry

We are Americans and travel to Bkk about once a year and a couple of years ago my son was flagged for frequent visits even though it isn't the case.  He was told that he needs to get a visa next time.  So the last 2 times he got a visa from the Embassy.  He hasn't been in BKK for about 1.5 years now.  My question is, does he need to get a visa for our trip next week or will he be able to get his visa exempt stamp at the airport?

Comment: Have you asked the embassy?

Comment: Although @dbkk answer makes a good point, can you edit your answer to demonstrate the previous 2-3 year entry/exit history to any port of Thailand for your son?  We need a complete history to maximize giving you the best answer.  This should be recorded in the passport used.

Answer (score 4):

Thai immigration rules are not clearly defined or properly published and often in flux. There's plenty of speculation on the internet, but you won't be able to get a clear and reliable answer on this, even if you personally ask an immigration official. Similarly, embassy/consulate staff would be next-to-useless, since they're under a different ministry than immigration at the borders, and can't even access the immigration database. What is clear is that over the last several years, Thai Immigration has taken a bit of a dislike of frequent visitors.

I would keep getting the tourist visa prior to any future trip -- it's a long way to risk a rejection at the airport. Note that in addition to applying in person, you can also get a tourist visa for Thailand by mail at any consulate.